# String yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS convert to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

How can convert this string  yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS to datetime  in c#?

Comment: Minus one because this question shows no research effort on your part.  Surely googling this would have been pretty easy...

Comment: I didn't answer anything, and your comment doesn't make any sense.  If you hover your cursor over the down-vote button, the first thing shown for a reason is "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method and [define the exact format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) that you are expecting to receive :

```
// This will parse a DateTime object using the "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" format 
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input,"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

This assumes that the `Y` characters will represent a two-digit year and the `S` characters you were looking for would be considered fractional seconds, which have been converted to the `y` and `f` formats respectively.

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HYTE23).

Comment: rion I will try your answer

Comment: I've added [an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HYTE23) that you can use to test it out.

Comment: Thanks Rion.it is working fine.Some people dont  enough read my question so he give me minus point .But you understand me correct so very thanks .